# Como o Android Studio/Gradle resolve conflitos de dependências (diferentes versões de uma mesma lib) e como resolver sem Gradle/Maven?

Tags: java, android

Eu possuo um aplicativo para Android, e este aplicativo é escrito em outra linguagem, e compilado para um `.so` e então criado um pequeno Java e Manifest. A compilação do código envolve basicamente: `d8`, `aapt`, `javac` e, por fim, `apksign`. Ou seja, não há Gradle ou coisa deste tipo.

---

Entretanto para utilizar alguns recursos é necessário bibliotecas de terceiros, por exemplo: o "Sign in with Google" e o "Google Play Payments", assim como outras bibliotecas de publicidade.

Vamos supor que eu esteja a utilizar duas bibliotecas:

- AndroidX Browser
- Play Services Auth

Mas, estas duas bibliotecas também dependem de outras, por exemplo, ambas dependem do:

- AndroidX Core (androidx.core)

O problema é que um deles possui um `pom.xml` que indica a versão 1.0.0 e outro que indica a versão 1.1.0.

---

Se eu simplesmente tiver dois `AAR` (e consequentemente tiver dois `JAR`), eles dão conflito, uma vez que um já definiu as coisas do outro. Então, ao menos para o `d8` eu só posso importar um deles.

**A questão é, como posso importar os dois ou como eu devo escolher qual importa?**

Como eu não uso Gradle/Android Studio/Maven (...), eu não sei como eles se comportam nesta situação, por isso queria saber como eles resolvem e como posso resolver sem eles.